# 8.10 LAB: Thesaurus - Output is not correct, I don't know why

Tags: java, arrays

The lab instructions:

> Given a set of text files containing synonyms for different words,
> complete the main program to output the synonyms for a specific word.
> Each text file contains synonyms for the word specified in the file’s
> name, and each row within the file lists the word’s synonyms that
> begin with the same letter, separated by a space. The program reads a
> word and a letter from the user and opens the text file associated
> with the input word. The program then stores the contents of the text
> file into a two-dimensional array predefined in the program. Finally
> the program searches the array and outputs all the synonyms that begin
> with the input letter, one synonym per line, or a message if no
> synonyms that begin with the input letter are found.
>
> Hints: Use ASCII values to map the row index of the array to the first
> letter of a word when storing the synonyms into the array. Ex: Index 0
> to an 'a', index 25 to a 'z'. Assume all letters are in lowercase.
>
> Ex: If the input of the program is:
>
> ```
> educate c
> ```
>
> the program opens the file educate.txt, which contains:
>
> ```
> brainwash brief
> civilize coach cultivate
> develop discipline drill
> edify enlighten exercise explain
> foster
> improve indoctrinate inform instruct
> mature
> nurture
> rear
> school
> train tutor
> ```
>
> then the program outputs:
>
> ```
> civilize
> coach
> cultivate
> ```
>
> Ex: If the input of the program is:
>
> ```
> educate a
> ```
>
> then the program outputs:
>
> ```
> No synonyms for educate begin with a.
> ```

If the input is

```
educate c
```

My output only prints

```
coach and cultivate
```

it's not adding the word `civilize`.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NUM_CHARACTERS = 26;
        int MAX_WORDS = 10;

        String[][] synonyms = new String[NUM_CHARACTERS][MAX_WORDS];
        String[] words;

        String word = scnr.next();
        char letter = scnr.next().charAt(0);

        FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(word + ".txt");
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHARACTERS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORDS; j++) {
                synonyms[i][j] = "";
            }
        }

        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            words = line.split(" ");
            char firstLetter = words[0].charAt(0);
            int index = firstLetter - 'a';

            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                synonyms[index][i - 1] = words[i];
            }
        }

        int index = letter - 'a';
        boolean found = false;

        for (String synonym : synonyms[index]) {
            if (!synonym.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(synonym);
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("No synonyms for " + word + " begin with " + letter + ".");
        }

        fileScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Here are the text files:

**happy.txt**

```
blessed blest blissful
cheerful contented
delighted
ecstatic elated
glad
joyful joyous jubilant
lively
merry
overjoyed
peaceful pleasant pleased
thrilled
upbeat
```

**goal.txt**

```
objective
```

**educate.txt**

```
brainwash brief
civilize coach cultivate
develop discipline drill
edify enlighten exercise explain
foster
improve indoctrinate inform instruct
mature
nurture
rear
school
train tutor
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `synonyms[index][i - 1] = words[i];` consider what values `i` can be and where in `words` "civilized" is.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem lies in your second for loop, this is what it should say instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    synonyms[index][i] = words[i];
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Also for some reason, this was throwing a NullPointerException on my side:

```
for (String synonym : synonyms[index]) {
    if (!synonym.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(synonym);
        found = true;
    }
}
```

But a "try/catch" statement fixes this!

```
try {
    if (!synonym.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(synonym);
        found = true;
    }
}
catch(NullPointerException nfe) {}
```

---

For anyone else trying this problem for themselves on an IDE, I'd recommend copying the file path of "educate.txt". It will save you a LOT of file not found exceptions!

[image: Copy File Path On Replit]

On Replit you can just right-click the file and then select "Copy file path". Then just do something like this:

```
FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream (((rest of file path) + word + ".txt").trim());
```

or in my case:

```
FileInputStream fileByteStream = new FileInputStream (("src/main/java/" + word + ".txt").trim());
```